# SignalR Autofac Inject Authorize Attribute

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, attributes, signalr, autofac

I'm trying to figure out a way to inject dependencies into my `AuthorizeAttribute` in SignalR similar to the way it is done in WebAPI.

In Web API I know I can call `builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(config);` but I can't quite seem to find an equivalent for SignalR. The closest thing I can find that looks like it might do the trick is the `PropertiesAutowired()` method.

I have tried `builder.RegisterType<MyAuthorizationAttribute>.PropertiesAutowired();` where my attribute looks like

```
public class MyAuthorizationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public IRepository Repository { get; set; }

    public override bool AuthorizeHubConnection(HubDescriptor hubDescriptor, 
        IRequest request)
    {
        Repository.QueryStoredProcedure("Test");
        ...
    }

    protected override bool UserAuthorized(IPrincipal user)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

But the instance of `Repository` is null every time.

Comment: Are you able to inject dependencies in your hubs?

Comment: @Matei_Radu Yep. That works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

According to http://eworldproblems.mbaynton.com/2012/12/signalr-hub-authorization/

Register your MyAuthorizationAttribute in Autofac:

```
builder.RegisterType<MyAuthorizationAttribute>().PropertiesAutowired();
```

then before app.MapSignalR():

```
 var myModule = container.Resolve<MyAuthorizationAttribute >(); 
 GlobalHost.HubPipeline.AddModule(new AuthorizeModule(myModule, myModule));
```

With this piece of code, you can set **global** authorize modules for hub connections and for method invocation.

> Optionally, this module may be instantiated with
>   IAuthorizeHubConnection and IAuthorizeHubMethodInvocation authorizers
>   that will be applied globally to all hubs and hub methods.

Read more here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.hubs.authorizemodule(v=vs.118).aspx