# Autofac with Signalr AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: dependency-injection, signalr, autofac

I'm using SignalR for making a real-time web application and I'm writing a custom authorize attribute for SignalR methods.

One thing is difficult to me now is to inject repositories to my attribute. 
I think PropertiesAutowired() could do the work but it didn't.

Can anyone help me please ?

Thank you,

Comment: See my answer in related problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/38975001/2823106

Comment: Thank you, I also found the solution for my project somehow, its similar to yours.